# I get AnonymusUser in Ajax GET request DJANGO

Tags: django, ajax, get

I am working in a Django application and I need to get some data with a GET request from a template. I have set up a AJAX get request as follows:

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: "json",
         url: "https://www.url.com/enpd/var1/var2/var3",
         xhrFields: {
             withCredentials: true
         },
         success: function(obj) {
           ...
         },
         error: function(data) {
           ...
         }
       });
```

And in the views.py I have the following:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def getReq(request, var1, var2, var3):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
       ...
    else:
       return HttpResponse({user})
```

And I always get the request user as "AnonymusUser". It's like the AJAX get request is not sending the user details in the request. Why is that happening? I have read through many posts and nothing helped...

PD: I created a custom user, don't know if that may cause any issue?

Custom User Model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager

class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: Share full code of ajax and view, also share custom user model.

Comment: I have added the Custom User model, as the views and ajax are already shared. The problem in the views is that the request.user is anonymous, so the content inside the .is_authenticated() is not relevant... @SunderamDubey

Answer (score 0):

are you added this to settings?:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "your_app_name.User"
```

Comment: Yes, otherwise i wouldn't be able to login....